# ASP NET.CORE MVC Динамическое создание <input>

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Пишу сайт - квизер. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть Некий опрос, с N-ым количеством вопросов, нужно при нажатии на кнопочку, добавлять новое поле для нового вопроса(больше тавтологии богу тавтологии),
Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И получаем такой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нужно так нужно, но какие с этим проблемы?

Comment: я не совсем понимаю как это реализовать.

Comment: что то сами пытались сделать? Есть какие то мысли, наработки?

Comment: да, в js пока копаюсь,  в onClick удалять кнопку, добавлять в InnerHTML контейнера для вопросов новое поле, и в новый элемент добавлять эту же кнопку.  но это выглядит как-то вычерно для такого фреймворка. Да и я шарпист, хотелось бы такое по возможности, делать в обход JS'a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Создаем Model**

```
public class AddQuizViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Название")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Заказчик")]
    public string Customer { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Список вопросов")]
    public List<string> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

**Создаем View**

```
@model AddQuizViewModel

<div class="text-center">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <h2 class="display-4">Новый Квиз</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "field-validation-error" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer, null, new { @class = "field-validation-error" })
        </div>
        <h1 class="display-4">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Questions)</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Добавить вопрос" onclick="newField()"/>
            </div>
            <div id="questions" class="col-9"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Сохранить"/>
    }
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddQuiz(AddQuizViewModel model)
{
    // логика и вся остальная обработка
}
```

**Пишем JS для добавления поля**

```
function newField() {
    // определяем контейнер для хранения полей с вопросами
    let container = document.getElementById("questions"); 
    // получаем текущее количество input (полей для вопросов)
    let fieldCount = container.getElementsByTagName("input").length;
    // увеличиваем Id для нового поля
    let nextFieldId = fieldCount + 1;

    // здесь добавляем элемент, который будет хранить input (в моем случае, у вас может быть по другому или вообще не быть его)
    let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("class", "form-group");

    // создаем новое поле с новым id, name ДОЛЖЕН СОВПАДАТЬ С ИМЕНЕМ ПОЛЯ В МОДЕЛИ!!!
    let field = document.createElement("input");
        field.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
        field.setAttribute("id", "Questions[" + nextFieldId + "]");
        field.setAttribute("name", "Questions");
        field.setAttribute("type", "text");
        field.setAttribute("placeholder", "Введите текст вопроса");

    // добавляем поле в <div class="form-group"></div>
    div.appendChild(field);
    // добавляем <div class="form-group"><input ... /></div> в главный контейнер
    container.appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот моя реализация, но это на JS, и ASP NET тут вообще не причём.

```
let containerId = 'quiz_wrapper'          
let btnId = `i_new_field_button`;

let fieldHtml =`<input type="text" name="Question" placeholder="Вопрос" value="" />`

function AddNewField() {

    let divElem = document.getElementById(containerId);
    let newElem = document.createElement('div');
    let btn = document.getElementById(btnId);

    newElem.innerHTML += fieldHtml;
    newElem.innerHTML += btn.outerHTML;
    btn.remove();
    divElem.appendChild(newElem);


}
```

код контроллера, для того, чтобы собрать все вопросы

```
 public ActionResult Create(IFormCollection collection)
        {
            var questions = collection["Question"];

            return View();
        }
```

Соответственно, вопрос всё ещё в силе. Можно ли сделать тоже самое силами ASP.NET CORE MVC?

Comment: отлично, а в контроллер-то значения новых полей придут?)

Comment: @tCode, пока не должно, щас буду дальше ковырять

Comment: @tCode, теперь будет :3